# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 argument, 0 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error. the thing it should do is update the table in the database and my view order but i only get this error. How do i fix it any idea?

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_error() expects
> exactly 1 argument, 0 given in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\final\Admin\edit1.php:108
> Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\final\Admin\edit1.php(108): mysqli_error()
> #1 {main}
> thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\final\Admin\edit1.php on line 108

File name:edit1.php

My Codes

```
<?php $status = ""; if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1) { $id=$_REQUEST['id']; $name =$_REQUEST['name']; $email =$_REQUEST['email']; $phone=$_REQUEST['phone']; $address=$_REQUEST['address']; $mode=$_REQUEST['pmode']; $products=$_REQUEST['products']; $amount_paid=$_REQUEST['amount_paid']; $Status=$_REQUEST['Status']; $update="update orders set name='".$name."', email='".$email."', phone='".$phone."', address='".$address.",'pmode='".$mode."', products='".$products."', amount_paid='".$amount_paid."', Status='".$Status."' where id='".$id."'"; mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error()); $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='view1.php'>View Updated Record</a>"; echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>'; }else { ?>
```

My button Codes/placeholder

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="">  <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" /> <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" /> <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" /></p> <p><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" /></p> <p><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" required value="<?php echo $row['phone'];?>" /></p> <p><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address" required value="<?php echo $row['address'];?>" /></p> <p><input type="text" name="pmode" placeholder="Enter Payment Mode" required value="<?php echo $row['pmode'];?>" /></p> <p><input type="text" name="products" placeholder="Enter products" required value="<?php echo $row['products'];?>" /></p> <p><input type="text" name="amount_paid" placeholder="Enter Amount Paid" required value="<?php echo $row['amount_paid'];?>" /></p> <p><select name="Status" required value="<?php echo $row['Status'];?>" class="form-control">
          <option value="" selected disabled>-Select Status-</option>
          <option value="Incomplete">Incomplete</option>
          <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
        </select> </p> <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update" /></p>
```

Comment: The error is on line 108, which we can't see. The error says that `mysqli_error` on line 108 expects arguments, but you gave it none.

Comment: forgot to specify line 108..line 108 is 'mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());'....also i new to this stuff i have no idea what argument it is expecting me to give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `mysqli_error` you have to provide the connection object, according to the docs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

You are calling mysql_error like this: `mysql_error()` which is incorrect.

I cannot see in your code where you create the mysql connection but lets pretend it is a variable named `$conn`. You should change `mysql_error()` to `mysql_error($conn)`

Comment: i tried to change the 'mysql_error()' to 'mysql_error($con)' but the error im getting now is 
                                                                                                                                           
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'pmode='COD', products='1 Liter Milk(50)', amount_paid='500', Status='Complete...' at line 1'

Comment: and my line 1 is php code for session start

Comment: That is expected, of course. It was trying to call `mysql_error()` initially because you have an error in your mysql statement.

Comment: So, review the error you can now see and adjust your MySQL statement as necessary, as you can now see the error